# Formatting json content in jquery mobile list view

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-mobile

Am creating an application in jquery mobile which the final output should be similar to this:

[image]

The raw html code that produces that image is

```
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li data-role="list-divider">Today, May 1, 2016 <span class="ui-li-count">2</span></li>
      <li><a href="#">
        <h3>Reply</h3>
        <p>20,00 we do have discounts for earlier payers </p>


        <p class="ui-li-aside">10 mins ago</p>
      </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">
        <h4>Me</h4>
        <p>How much is the current fee per semester? Do you accet credit cards</p>
        <p class="ui-li-aside">25 mins ago</p>
      </a></li>
      <li data-role="list-divider">Yesterday, April 30, 2016 <span class="ui-li-count">1</span></li>
      <li><a href="#">
        <h3>Reply</h3>
        <p>Hello, How can i help you?</p>
        <p class="ui-li-aside">10:15 pm</p>
      </a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider">Friday, April 29, 2016 <span class="ui-li-count">1</span></li>
      <li><a href="#">
        <h3>Me</h3>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p class="ui-li-aside">10:15 pm</p>
      </a></li>
     </ul>
```

In my project am using json to fetch data from the database and show it to the user in a listview like above.

Code to fetch data from the database:

```
  var id_from = localStorage.loggedin_id;
  var id_to_send = localStorage.user_schoolls_head;
 $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1/tum_old/custom/php/message.php",  
{id_from:id_from,id_to_send:id_to_send},
function(response){
console.log(response); 
});
```

After the console.log(response) i get the javascript object as:

[image]

A from the picture with the list a me situation is like the one for from_id and then to_id (example 1:4) while a reply is the vice versa.
How can i format the time to display :

```
Today, yeasterday...from hence(on) it will display the dats on the list dividers
Time to show 10mins ago, 20mins ago, but beyond 1 hour it shows the actual time (eg: 10:15pm)
How to also sort these messages according to dates so that 
the earliest is seen first in the today area..
```

ie: IT SHOULD APPEAR LIKE THE FIRST IMAGE

MY DATABASE RECORD:
[image]

Comment: Look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ta793zx2/47/
Is this (almost) what you are looking for?

Comment: It almost there but how do i add the list dividers based on the date

Comment: You could check the date against an array. If it's not there, generate divider HTML code and push the date to the array.

Comment: Dou you have an example on how exactly to push the date in the array(what do you mean)

Comment: Please do not edit your post such that it invalidates other answers. Instead, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DerpyNerd/gyzkbuqn/5/).

It would be very unwise to sort your objects using javascript.
Like Zoran said, you should do that in your query using `ORDER BY time_sent DESC`.

**Update**
Not sure what you mean by *divider based on date* but I've updated the jsfiddle to output exactly how the date is formatted in your example.
Hope it helps.

Comment: What about the list dividers based on the date

Answer (score 1):

To format dates you can use momentjs (http://momentjs.com). Sorting can be achieved simply by adding `ORDER BY time_sent DESC` in your sql query